# Excel countif function with cell references in second parameter

Tags: excel

Let's say I'm trying to count the number of rows where the value in column A is greater than in column B and the data I have is that A1 to A10 has the numbers 1 up to 10 and B1 to B10 has the numbers 10 down to 1.

The forumula I've constructed is

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10, ">"&B1:B10)
```

The correct result would be 5 but if I place this formula in row 10 I get the result of 9. Also, I get different results if I place this exact same function in different cells.

It seems to be the cell references as the second parameter that breaks the function as something like `=COUNTIF(A1:A10, ">4")` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Countif accepts a single condition so if you place that formula to third row, it will compare the array to `B3`; if you place it to 7th row, it will compare the array to `B7`.

You can try the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10>B1:B10))
```

It will compare the arrays elementwise and return boolean values. `--` ensures those boolean values are converted to 0's and 1's. And it sums them up at the end. This function normally takes the multiplication of several arrays (hence the name sumproduct) but here we are using it on only one array to make use of its ability to work on arrays element-wise. You can give other conditions as well:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10>B1:B10), --(A1:A10<4))
```